# Is there a way to set a default value for a property mediator if the property does not exist in the request body?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I am building a simple API in WSO2 EI/ESB. I am saving each of the request parameters to properties like so:

```
<property expression="json-eval($.client_id)" name="client_id" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

And then building a payload using the payload factory:

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>       
                    {

                        "req_type": "1",
                        "client_id": $1

                    }
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('client_id')"/>
                </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

However, if I sent an empty message `{}` (without the client_id) then nothing is placed in the $1 argument and the resulting payload will not validate:

```
{
                    "req_type": "1",
                    "client_id:
}
```

What I would like to know is if there is a way to set a default value when saving this expression in the property mediator? For example:
`<property expression="json-eval($.client_id)" name="client_id" scope="default" type="STRING" defaultValue="0"/>` or something like that.

I am aware I can implement filters to check whether the field exists and validate it but I find that can become a bit cluttered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't using payloadFactory. You have to choose from different solutions:

- Replace your payloadFactory with XSLT transformation which is way more flexible (best solution)
- Add a filter to build your parameter and set a value for default
- Use a script mediator to replace the painful filter and be able to manage if/then/else statements easily. You can then initialize the property from the script mediator.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I was a bit doubtful that there would be a way to do it, just thought I should ask the community. I will look at using the XSLT transformation or a script mediator, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do that. You will have to use filters.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional xpath ?
This might work. Play around with code underneath.

```
<enrich>
    <source clone="true" type="custom" xpath="0"  />
    <target action="replace" type="custom" xpath="" property="boolean(string-length(//client_id) != 0)" />
</enrich>
```